# Getting Physical Path in SWF File

Tags: actionscript-3, path, flash, uiloader

I'm using UILoaders to load different .swf files into the main .swf and am having a problem when I try to load a specific .swf file after a series of steps.

I wanted to know if there was a way to see which is the current path that the application is in so that I can know if my relative paths are working or if I have to change them.

I want to do something in the likes of this.path, or anything that works that way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the current url of your swf this way :

root.loaderInfo.url;